# Importing custom CA and personal SSL certificates into Ubuntu Touch web browser

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ssl

I need to make the web browser app on ubuntu phone to work with custom CA (PEM format) and personal SSL (PKCS12 format) certificates. Any idea how to import the certificates?

Comment: [This question on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/437330/how-do-you-add-a-certificate-authority-ca-to-ubuntu) might help answer your question

Comment: suggested solution using update-ca-certificates does not apply because:
a) in Ubuntu Touch /etc/ca-certificates and /usr/local/share/ca-certificates directories are on read-only filesystem
b) web browser app probably does not use this certificate store at all

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is NO (at least for now). The web browser does not support import of SSL certificates at all. It is reported as bug (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/webbrowser-app/+bug/1313370) but apparently nobody is working on it.

For people relying on use of custom or personal SSL certificates for web access this makes ubuntu touch phones/tablets unusable at the moment :(